How to create a platform from all transitive dependencies of an artifact?
I'm working on an application that has a dependency on a 3rd party artifact, which has many transitive dependencies itself. I need to implement some extension points for the 3rd party artifact and don't want to mess around with the dependencies it declares. The 3rd party artifact unfortunately doesn't provide a bom to make this task easy.
Therefore I would like to create a platform from all the transitive dependencies the 3rd party artifact declares itself. How can I do this?
Declaring
dependencies {
    api platform('org.example:foo:1.2.3')
    implementation 'jakarta.validation:jakarta.validation-api'
}

doesn't cause jakarta.validation-api to be resolved to version 3.1.0 which foo has a transitive dependency on.
